# SQL Server: how to do math calculations in a string?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have an application that allows calculations on input data before writing it to a table.

None of the calculations can be done in C#, all must be done in T-SQL.

The application builds an insert statement with possible nested calculations based on user input.

One sample is an integer that is divided by 10 and then cast to `varchar`.

```
 CAST(( ' ( CAST( 6828 AS BIGINT)) /10' ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) ,
```

This is part of a larger INSERT statement that is built based on user interface input.

How would I get the inner part `( CAST( 6828 AS BIGINT)) /10` executed first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sp_executesql` to execute an entire string.  For instance:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT CAST( CAST( 6828 AS BIGINT)) /10 AS NVARCHAR(MAX))';
```

[See more here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170.aspx)

Comment: This doesn't compile - I think it should be this: `EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT CAST( (CAST(6828 AS BIGINT) /10) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))'`